How build submodel gluon project with maven?
There , i have a project named meeting ,and there is two submodel module named meeting-common and meeting-gui , i tried use gluon-cli to build project , but it occues error ,the stack is following
[Mon May 13 09:45:19 UTC 2024][SEVERE] Failed copying /home/runner/work/Meeting/Meeting/target/classes to /tmp/classes11104874000357322298: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/runner/work/Meeting/Meeting/target/classes
Check the log files under /home/runner/work/Meeting/Meeting/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/runner/work/Meeting/Meeting/target/classes

here is the command i used

mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build gluonfx:package -pl meeting-gui -am

the project link is  github action
I guess the error root is that the command is build under parent path , but when the meeting-gui is builded , gluonfx plugin default behavior is looking up the target class under the parent path which is  meeting/target/, the truely path is meeting/meeting-gui/target. Is there any way to  make the gluon plugin find the target class in correct way ? or configature the right path as meeting/meeting-gui/target.
